# How to @contextmenu (on right click) v-item in the array to display the menu list vueJs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

i want @contextmenu (on right click) in the v-list-item to show menu list. if enough there is a better solution please help me. 
 this is an example code that i have made.!! 
**template**

in v-list-item @contextmenu i have send **room.showMenu** to the function open()

```
<template>
  <v-list>
   <v-list-item-group v-model="model">
    <v-list-item
      v-for="(room, i) in rooms"
      :key="i"
      @contextmenu="open($event, room.showMenu)"
   >
      <v-list-item-content>
         <v-list-item-title>{{room.title}}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
      <v-menu
        v-model="room.showMenu"
         :position-x="x"
         :position-y="y"
         absolute
         offset-y
      >
       <v-list>
         <v-list-item @click.stop="delete(room.id)">
           <v-list-item-title>delete</v-list-item-title>
         </v-list-item>
       </v-list>
     </v-menu>
     </v-list-item>
   </v-list-item-group>
  </v-list>
</template>
```

**script**

```
<script>
data() {
    return {
      model: null,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      rooms: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "room 1",
        showMenu: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "room 2",
        showMenu: false
      }
      ],
    }
  },
methods: {
      open(e, showMenu) {
        e.preventDefault()
        showMenu = false
        this.x = e.clientX
        this.y = e.clientY
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          showMenu = true
        })
      },
     delete(id){
        console.log('id :>> ', id);
     },
    },
</script>
```